# Metrics on $\mathbb{R}^k$ that don't behave well with respect to sums

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^k$ ($k\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$), endowed with a metric $d$. Let also $(x_n)_n$, $(y_n)_n$ be two sequences in $X$ convergent to $x,y\in X$ respectively, that is $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ and $d(y_n,y)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

If $d$ is induced by a norm, then it is easy to show (using the triangular inequality) that the sequence $(x_n+y_n)_n$ converges to $x+y$, i.e. $d(x_n+y_n,x+y)\to 0$.

While it is clear in the proof where the norm assumption is used, I still have not managed to construct a counterexample for the convergence of $(x_n+y_n)_n$ to $x+y$ when $d$ is not induced by a norm. I think that at least a non-constructive proof of existence of a suitable $d$ should be doable by means of the axiom of choice, but I have managed to prove that either yet. Ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is whether or not vector addition is continuous with respect to your given metric. Metrics given by norms always are, by construction.

Comment: A simple recipe to construct a metric in which addition is discontinuous: Choose a discontinuous injective function $f$ and define $d(x,y)=\|f(x)-f(y)\|$. Then you can choose the sequences such that $x+y$ lies on the discontinuity.

Comment: @Rahul +1 to this

Comment: It occurs to me that norms are associated with vectors, and $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a vector space.  Have you considered non-vector spaces? Granted, you may be able to define a metric that isnt induced from a norm, but from what I recall, in any vector space a metric induces a norm in turn. Does that induced norm then induce a metric again? Is it the same metric as the first? I dont know, I havent studied this too much. It just seems you might be caught in some sort of loop here stemming from the fact youre using vector spaces.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, that is exactly was I was trying to prove with the Axiom of Choice

Comment: Why do you need the axiom of choice? Choose any discontinuous function, for example $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto x+\operatorname{sgn}x$.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, you are right, that's easier than what I was doing. Then you pick $x_n=1+1/n$, $y_n=-1+1/n$ and you see that $x_n\to 1$, $y_n\to -1$, but $d(x_n+y_n,0)\to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If we put a norm on $\Bbb R^n$ then they are all equivalent, so the metrics from them give the same standard topology on $\Bbb R^n$. And as addition is continuous, we always have, purely from topology, $x_n \to x, y_n \to y \implies x_n + y_n \to x+y$.

If we have a different metric on $\Bbb R^n$ which induces a *different* topology on $\Bbb R^2$, then we can make examples: e.g. for the river metric (defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2168950/4280)) on $\Bbb R^2$ we have $(1+\frac1n, 0) \to (1,0)$, $(0,1+\frac1n) \to (0,1)$ but $(1+\frac1n, 1+\frac1n)\not \to (1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt.

define the metric $d(x,y)$ as follows.
$$
d(x,y)=   \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        |x - y| & \text{for }|x|,|y|<1\\
        \, \delta(x-y) & \text{otherwise}\\
        \end{array}\right\} 
$$
where $|\cdot|$ is standard norm in $\mathbb{R}^k$ (root square norm) , $\delta(x-y) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        1 & \text{for }x \neq y\\
        0 & \text{for }x = y\\
        \end{array}\right\} $

nonnegativity, identity and symmetry (for metric) is clear.

For show transitivity, enough to consider following two cases.

1 . $x,y$ are in 1 - ball and $z$  is at outside :

$d(x,y) = |x-y|<2$ , $d(y,z) = d(x,z) = 1$

2 . $x$ is in 1 - ball and $y,z$  are at outside :

$d(x,y) = d(x,z) = 1$ , $d(y,z)$ is $0$ or $1$.

$$\\$$
(maybe) $d(x,y)$ is really a metric.

---

Now, let consider $(x_n) = [\frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{10 n}]e_1 $.

Then  $x_n \to \frac{2}{3}e_1\,\,$ in $(\mathbb{R}^k , d).\quad$ ($|x_n| , |\frac{2}{3}e_1| < 1$)

However, since $2x_n = x_n + x_n = [\frac{4}{3} - \frac{1}{5 n}]e_1$ have radius greater than 1, 
$$d(2x_n,2x_m) = 1 \quad\forall n\neq m .$$

This means $(2x_n)$ can not converge to any other point.